# Claws-Mail can't find its dictionaries for spell checking

Tags: dictionary, fedora-13, claws-mail

Claws-Mail cannot find for whatever reason its spell checking files.

What you see in the picture, is what pop up, when I click the "compose mail" button.

What's happening here?

Mind, you, that is an *old* `.claws-mail` directory, taken from another installation, and copied back after upgrading the system to Fedora 13.

Cheers,
--polemon

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, I've solved it:

The dictionaries for claws-mail are the **hunspell-*** packages.

Installing hunspell-en solved the issue.

Comment: and if you need languages you don't find under hunspell, try then myspell.